# My application crashes before asking for permissions

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

when running the application for the first time it crashes (nothing on logcat). then you can see the requests for permissions and after you give the permission you can open the application and it works fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String [] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    int PERMISSION_ALL  = 1;

    Button record;
    Button play;
    Button stop;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

    String outPutFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //---------------------
        //asking for permission
        //---------------------

        if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }
        record = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recordbutton);
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);

        if (outPutFile==null){
            play.setEnabled(false);
        }

        stop.setEnabled(false);

        outPutFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outPutFile);

        //---------------------
        //recording
        //---------------------

        record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                mediaRecorder.start();
                record.setEnabled(false);
                stop.setEnabled(true);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"recording", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.release();
                mediaRecorder = null;
                stop.setEnabled(false);
                play.setEnabled(true);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        //---------------------
        //playing the record
        //---------------------

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                try {
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outPutFile);
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio Playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                mediaPlayer.start();

                record.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });


    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Why is that?

logcat-

```
07-30 19:03:03.812 4491-4491/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder, PID: 4491
                                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder/com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
                                                                                           at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Native Method)
                                                                                           at com.example.tsuryohananov.voicerecorder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:64)
                                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
                                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: obviously requestPermissions is not blocking call

Comment: your logcat please

Comment: the problem is with:     mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

Comment: I solved the problem, thank you all

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept that answer, or delete your question. This will take the question off the unanswered questions list and maybe help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved that codes:

```
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outPutFile);
```

to

```
    record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outPutFile);
            try {
                mediaRecorder.prepare();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            record.setEnabled(false);
            stop.setEnabled(true);
            mediaRecorder.start();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"recording", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

problem was that at first running the             mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

were running before the user gave the permissions.

I assume that there is other ways, maybe like:

```
    if (hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outPutFile);

    }
```